# Getting 404 error on JAX-RS web service/ Maven/Eclipse/Tomcat 9

Tags: jax-rs, http-status-code-404

**I am trying to show the Alien Object in XML format with AlienResouces as Resource.However, it is giving me 404 error during runtime on the browser and the debugging stmnt *GeAlien called* is not showing on Tomcat console**

> Web Service

```
package com.dip.testproj;
            import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
            @XmlRootElement
            public class Alien {
                private String name;
                private int points;
                public String getName() {
                    return name;
                }
                public void setName(String name) {
                    this.name = name;
                }
                public int getPoints() {
                    return points;
                }
                public void setPoints(int points) {
                    this.points = points;
                }
                
            
            }
```

**The following is the Resource for the Alien object. The object Alien is getting the resource Name   and Number and trying to display it on the browser during runtime.**

> We Service Resources

```
 package com.dip.testproj  
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    @Path("aliens")
    public class AlienResources {
        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        public Alien getAlien(){
            System.out.println("getAlien Called");
            Alien a1 = new Alien();
            a1.setName("Navin");
            a1.setPoints(60);
            return a1;
            
        }
}
```

**There is no compilation error or any error on the console for Tomcat. server. However, it is giving "404" or "Resource could not be found" while trying to run the [THIS](http://localhost:8080/webapi/aliens) on the FF  browser**

**The URL Pattern on WEB.xml looks like this.**

> WEB.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.dip.testproj</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: can you please provide uri

Comment: check your jar  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the web.xml file with the code.